# check if user input value matches JSON entry ID/value

Tags: jquery, json

Here is what my JSON looks like (each data entry/set) via /`locations.json`

```
{
 "20101":{ // I use zip value as an entry ID, so check if this matches .val()
    "Zipcode":"20101",
    "City":"",
    "Primary State":"Virginia",
    "Lotto":"49530",
    "County":"Loudoun"
} // .... etc more entries
```

Here is my web form HTML mark-up:

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" name="Zipcode" id="Zipcode" value="" maxlength="5" placeholder="Zipcode">
   <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

- I am just trying to check if my #`ZipCode` value via my input tag
  equals that of my JSON id, so in my JSON example above `20101`.
- I am successfully console logging when there is a match (*i.e. below
  line*); but I need to do it in a `if` or `for` statement as I have to
  continue handling the data before and after it.

**console.log(myjson[ZipSearch]);** *# Works but I need to handle in if or for statement*

Heres the jQuery; I have tried defining my JSON as a `const` and a few other things; including `filter` / any Ideas how I can simply check for this *match* in a *if* or *for* statement so I can continue handling my data?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var ZipSearch = $("#Zipcode").val();
        console.log(ZipSearch)
        var myjson;
        $.getJSON("locations/locations.json", function(json) {
            myjson = json;
            console.log(myjson[ZipSearch]); 

        });
    });
});
```

*latest attempt:* (but it always returns as failed)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var ZipSearch = $("#Zipcode").val();
        console.log(ZipSearch)
        var myjson;
        $.getJSON("locations/locations.json", function(json) {
            myjson = json;
            for (var key in json) {
                // console.log(key);
                if (key === ZipSearch) {
                    console.log("Pass")
                    console.log(myjson[ZipSearch]); 
                    $('.error').hide();
                } else { 
                    console.log("Fail")
                    $('.error').show();
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So where is your attempt at an if statement?  You're not showing your attempt to use the value inside the getJSON callback.

Comment: Keeping in mind that you have to do that conditional logic **inside** the getJSON callback.

Answer (score 1):

try this instead. If your doing for loop then you have to break it once its pass. 
But doing a for loop is a waste of time, try to find if the variable exist instead.

Have a look below

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var ZipSearch = $("#Zipcode").val();
            console.log(ZipSearch)
            var myjson;
            $.getJSON("locations/locations.json", function(json) {
                myjson = json;
                if (myjson[ZipSearch]){// if exist 
                        console.log("Pass")
                        console.log(myjson[ZipSearch]); 
                        $('.error').hide();
                }else {
                      console.log("Fail")
                      $('.error').show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```